# Cascade delete child rows when parent is deleted on same table in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, cascading-deletes, ef-core-2.0

The following is the entity on data context. I want to delete child zones when a parent zone is deleted.

I tried

1. cascade delete. This did not survive migration.
2. recursively listing all zones that should be deleted when zone z is deleted and use RemoveRange to delete all items in the list. It still throws an exception saying

Error:

> DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint

How do I delete items with such a simple relationship?

```
public class Zone
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
        public virtual Zone ParentZone { get; set; }
}

public class ZoneDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ZoneDbContext(DbContextOptions<ZoneDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Zone> Zones { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked

```
public void DeleteMyEntity(MyEntity entity)
        {
            var target = MyEntities
                .Include(x => x.Children)
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == entity.Id);

            RecursiveDelete(target);

            SaveChanges();

        }

        private void RecursiveDelete(MyEntity parent)
        {
            if (parent.Children != null)
            {
                var children = MyEntities
                    .Include(x => x.Children)
                    .Where(x => x.ParentId == parent.Id);

                foreach (var child in children)
                {
                    RecursiveDelete(child);
                }
            }

            MyEntities.Remove(parent);
        }
```